# Sqlalchemy Float(8) stored in MySQL with 2 decimal places

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a Sqlalchemy model with `price` column requiring 6 decimal places. An example of data stored in `price` column is `71.150002`.

However when that number is inserted into the database by Sqlalchemy using pandas `.to_sql`, it appears that it is only stored in 2 decimal places, like `71.15`.

Why is this despite passing `8` to the `precision` parameter of `Float`?

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'price'
    date = Column(String(9))
    price = Column(Float(8))
    name = Column(String(10))
```

Comment: Did you check [Mysql data types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-data-types)?